# Convert batch script to sh

Tags: batch-file, sh

I am new with ubuntu, please help me convert these batch codes to sh, I am trying to run the files mentioned below and run as a service after installing. I already searched for answers but failed to find one.

```
    @echo off
echo Installing services
.\Central\GunBoundBroker3 -install
.\Server8360\GunBoundServ3 -install
.\Server8361\GunBoundServ3 -install
.\BuddyCenter\BuddyCenter2 -install
.\BuddyServ\BuddyServ2 -install

@echo off
echo Initiating Services
net start "GunBoundXPBroker[8372]"
net start "GunBoundXPServ[8360]"
net start "GunBoundXPServ[8361]"
net start "Buddy Central Service 2"
net start "Buddy Service 2" 

pause
```

Comment: What do those programs do?

Comment: Do you mean you want a Linux version of the Windows batch file you posted?

Comment: @UnknownOctopus: Yeah, just wanted to be sure that's what he meant as I'm not sure how he's ported windows services to Linux and thought maybe I was missing something

Comment: actually, those are exe files for a gunbound server, the first script will install the programs as a server and the second one will initiate the services. 

Once the batch script is initiated, this is the output http://i.imgur.com/KccN7fW.png please refer to this image.
Would it be possible to do the same on linux?


PS: Don't mind the error, haven't configured the files completely, But it will show the same "service was started successfully".

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you do not need @echo off; this is dos specific.

Secondly, create your script with the first line saying:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Thirdly, you will need to use forward slashes (`/`) rather than backslashes (`\`) in your filenames

Fourthly there isn't really an analogue to `net start` in Linux - [This question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18802/how-to-correctly-add-a-custom-daemon-to-init-d) for details of how to add custom init scripts if this is what you're after

I hope this helps - unfortunately without you ellaborating on what these files you're running do and where they're from, how you've ported them from Windows to Linux, etc I cannot be more specific